# GNU Flex regexp for negative numbers

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer

I'm parsing math expressions in my C program. I use flex (without bison or yacc)
Everything works ok except negative or explicit positive numbers. Here is my current rule for integers and operators

```
integer           -?([0-9]+)
.........
"-"                   {some action}
{integer}             {some action}
```

And so on. It's ok for expressions like "1+2+3" but fails on "1-2-3" as it treats it as negative numbers, not single subtraction operator. So I have to escape numbers with brackets "1-(2)-(3)" or spaces. But it looks ugly.

I tried "[+-]+[ ]*-([0-9]+)" for only negatives but doesn't work as it includes previous operators in the result. Of course I can pre-process a string in order to count "-" and "+" but may be it is possible with regex within flex?

Comment: Try this: `/(\d)([\+|-])?/g`

Comment: @Amir, `([\+|-])` should be `([+-])` or `(\+|-)`.

Comment: @Sam yes my mistake, I replaced parenthesis by square brackets without removing the pipe symbol: `/(\d)([\+-])?/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the numbers as positive integers, treating the leading `'-'` as a separate token that is interpreted syntactically (by bison/yacc) as either negation or subtraction depending on context.

So `-1234` would be two tokens: `'-'`, and `1234`.

Similarly for `'+'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is simpler then I thought. I use stack machine for evaluation, so unary minus and plus I implemented in a second. Thanks a lot

Comment: This works nicely. I have a minor case of handling negative INT_MIN e.g. -2147483648  on 32bit underflows because it's handled as (-)(2147483648).

Comment: The lexer should just return yytext. The parser should deal with the digit string in yytext after making a copy of it, prepending a negative sign if needed. Use strtol which will detect over/underflow for long, and you can also check against INT_MIN and INT_MAX for int.